# Seaborn and Pandas, grouped box plot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, boxplot

I'm pretty new to Python/data in general and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this

I currently have 3 data frames which look like this

```
| A | B | C | Type  | 
| 1 | 2 | 6 | Worst |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | Worst | 

| A | B | C | Type   | 
| 1 | 2 | 3 | Medium |

| A | B | C  | Type | 
| 1 | 5 | 20 | Worst|
```

I'm trying to create a grouped boxplot in which each A from the 3 types gets a boxplot and are grouped together, the same goes for B and C

I'm unsure of how to join all these data frames together so that I can send them into the seaborn catplot function. There doesn't seem to be much documentation on how to set up the data.

Comment: Since the dataframes all have the same columns, you can use ```concat``` to combine them. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Answer (score 1):

First concat the three dataframes with `concat` and then use seaborn to generate the boxplots from the resulting dataframe

```
import seaborn as sns

# generate the new data frame
df4 = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])

# Do the boxplot
sns.boxplot(data=df4, x='Type', y='A')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3], 'B':[2,6], 'C':[6,5] , 'Type':['Worst','Worst']})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1], 'B':[2], 'C':[3], 'Type':['Medium']})
data3 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1], 'B':[5], 'C':[20], 'Type':['Worst']})
df=pd.concat([data1,data2,data3], join='inner')
plt.figure(figsize= (6,10)
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
sns.boxplot(data=df, x ='A', y='Type')
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
sns.boxplot(data=df, x ='B', y='Type')
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
sns.boxplot(data=df, x ='C', y='Type')
plt.show()
```

[image]